# Inverse Laplace Transformation, Possible Step Function

Tags: laplace-transform

I have been asked to find the inverse Laplace transform of the following:

\begin{align}
F(s)=&\frac{(s-2)e^{-s}}{(s^2 -4s+3)}
\end{align}
I am having trouble breaking this down into easily transformed fractions. Obviously the denominator can be changed to $(s-3)(s-1)$, but I'm not sure where to go from that.

Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{s-2}{(s-1)(s-3)}=\frac{1/2}{s-3}+\frac{1/2}{s-1}$$

Comment: I think I see where to go. I will try to post an answer, thanks. @Dr. MV

Comment: So I have
\begin{align}
F(s)=(&\frac{1}{2}e^{-s})&(\frac{1}{(s-3)(s-1)})
\end{align}
 Does this turn into a convolution integral, or is there another way? Sorry if these are dumb questions. @Dr. MV

Comment: Bryan, note that the factor $e^{-s}$ transforms into a simple time shift $t-1$.  Does that help?

Comment: I found a simple way to do this problem @Dr. MV : Just complete the square in the denominator and use the $cosh$ Laplace transform.

Comment: @BryanChen There is usually more than one way to proceed.  Pleased to hear that you were able to find another way forward.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

Well, using the convolution theorem:

$$\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{e^\text{s}}\cdot\frac{\text{s}-2}{\text{s}^2-4\cdot\text{s}+3}\right]_{\left(t\right)}=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{e^\text{s}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\space*\space\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{s}-2}{\text{s}^2-4\cdot\text{s}+3}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Now, we also know:

$$\frac{\text{s}-2}{\text{s}^2-4\cdot\text{s}+3}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\frac{1}{\text{s}-1}+\frac{1}{\text{s}-3}\right\}\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{e^\text{s}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\space*\space\left\{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\text{s}-1}\right]_{\left(t\right)}+\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\text{s}-3}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\right)\right\}\tag3$$